# programmable search engine returns 400 Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: java, search-engine, google-search, google-search-api

When I call this url from Java code, postman or a web browser

```
URL:
https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCca5akhZ492pP08QBchz5Q4QA6kFYsBrc&cx=923a7bcc712ee431d&searchType=image&imgUrl=https://media.gq.com/photos/5a5f79d52316871dcb3c837f/master/w_1600,c_limit/Dua_Lipa_02.jpg
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest"
            }
        ],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use q argument to define image url instead of imageUrl

```
https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCca5akhZ492pP08QBchz5Q4QA6kFYsBrc&cx=923a7bcc712ee431d&searchType=image&q=https://media.gq.com/photos/5a5f79d52316871dcb3c837f/master/w_1600,c_limit/Dua_Lipa_02.jpg
```